# Derivative of the map $x \mapsto \frac{x}{|x|} $

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to compute the derivative of the map $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, defined by $f(x)=\frac{x}{|x|} $ where $|x|$ is the Euclidean norm.

Using the definition that the derivative of $f$ at **x** is the linear map $Df(x)$ such that $$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)-Df(x)(h)|}{|h|}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|\frac{x+h}{|x+h|} -\frac{x}{|x|}-Df(x)(h)|}{\sqrt{h_1^2+...+h_n^2}}=0.$$

I am unable to work with the definition above to see which map directly will give me the answer.

I know that if $Df(x)$ exists then it is the Jacobian of $f$ at **x** but how do I know it necessarily does and even then I am confused on how to compute the partials of this one. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use the product rule..

Comment: I thought of it, but what is the derivative of $\frac{1}{|x|}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: at the origin the derivative does not exist. At any other point the matrix of $Df(x)$ is simply $((\frac {\partial f_i} {\partial x_j}))$. Can you compute the partial derivatives?.

Comment: Do I need to use the formula $D(\frac{f}{g})(x) v= \frac{[Dg(x)]v}{f(x)} - \frac{ [Df(x)]v g(x)}{f(x)^2}?$ with partials instead of $D$?

Comment: @loststudent Yes, use the quotient rule to find partial derivatives.

Comment: I get $\frac{\partial  f_i }{\partial x_j} = \frac{x_1^2+...x_{i-1}^2+x_{i+1}^2+...+x^2_n}{(x_1^2+...+x_n^2)^{3/2}}$ for $i=j$ and 
$\frac{-x_i x_j}{(x_1^2+...+x_n^2)^{3/2}}$ otherwise.

But to claim that it is the derivative, don't we have to show that it exists in the first place?

Comment: @loststudent If $f$ has continuous partial derivatives in a neighborhood of  a point $x$ then the derivative $Df(x)$ exists.

Comment: Oh yes! These are indeed continuos away from the origin. Thank you.